'File' object has no attribute 'download'
async def handle_image(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """Обрабатывает изображение, отправленное пользователем."""
    # Останавливаем таймер, если график получен
    if 'timer' in context.user_data:
        context.user_data['timer'].cancel()
        del context.user_data['timer']

    # Получаем изображение, которое отправил пользователь
    photo = update.message.photo[-1]
    file = await photo.get_file()  # Получаем файл с Telegram

    # Получаем путь к файлу
    image_path = f"{photo.file_id}.jpg"  # Сохраняем изображение с уникальным ID

    # Скачиваем файл с помощью метода download_file
    image_as_file = await file.download()  # Получаем файл как байты
    with open(image_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(image_as_file)  # Сохраняем файл на диск

    # Сохраняем путь к изображению для дальнейшего анализа
    context.user_data['image_path'] = image_path
    
------------------------------------------------------------------
File "C:\Users\Admin\Bot.py", line 55, in handle_image
    image_as_file = await file.download()  # Получаем файл как байты
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'download'

Не понимаю почему файл не хочет сохраниться

Может, download_file(), как указано в комментарии? Не вдаваясь в подробности.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
